# CallInst constructor is private?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to build a simple version of a code analysis tool with LLVM.I have a few .ll files that contain the intermediate LLVM representation of certain programs and I'm trying to get the list of function calls that are performed in each function of the program.

This is my code, obtained thanks to the answers from my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160566/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-function-calls-that-are-performed-in-each-function-of).

```
void getFunctionCalls(const Module *M)
{

   for (const Function &F : *M) {
      for (const BasicBlock &BB : F) {
        for (const Instruction &I : BB) {
          if (CallInst callInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(I)) {
            if (Function *calledFunction = callInst->getCalledFunction())     {
              if (calledFunction->getName().startswith("llvm.dbg.declare")) {

                // Do something

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


}
```

When I compile it, I get an error saying :

```
home/kike/llvm-3.9.0.src/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h: In function ‘void getFunctionCalls(const llvm::Module*)’:

/home/kike/llvm-3.9.0.src/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1357:3: error: ‘llvm::CallInst::CallInst(const llvm::CallInst&)’ is private
```

**It means that the CallInst constructor is private?** In this case, **How can I do to get the list of function calls?**

**[Edit 1]:**

I have also tried to pass I as a reference, like this:

```
void getFunctionCalls(const Module *M)
{

   for (const Function &F : *M) {
      for (const BasicBlock &BB : F) {
        for (const Instruction &I : BB) {
          if (CallInst * callInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)) {
            if (Function *calledFunction = callInst->getCalledFunction())     {
              if (calledFunction->getName().startswith("llvm.dbg.declare")) {

                // Do something

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


}
```

And I get this error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘llvm::cast_retty<llvm::CallInst, const llvm::Instruction*>::ret_type {aka const llvm::CallInst*}’ to ‘llvm::CallInst*’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CallInst does not have a copy constructor because it was not meant to be passed by value. Use

```
const CallInst* callInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)
```

instead of

```
CallInst callInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(I)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried it. And I get and error saying:  invalid conversion from ‘llvm::cast_retty<llvm::CallInst, const llvm::Instruction*>::ret_type {aka const llvm::CallInst*}’ to ‘llvm::CallInst*’

Comment: I edited my answer, forgot the const keyword (the input argument for dyn_cast had the type const Instruction* and dyn_cast does not remove the const qualifier during the cast).